# Exclude an if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, include, require

Is it somehow possible to exclude an if statement to two different files? When I write something like the following code, it gives a parse error: `syntax error, unexpected end of file`. Apparently, i always have to close an if statement in the same included file. Is there a way to accomplish what i want?

index.php:

```
<?php
require "top.inc.php"; // opening the if statement
  some code to execute if statement in top.inc.php is true
require "bottom.inc.php"; // closing the if statement
?>
```

top.inc.php:

```
<?php if (1 == 1) { ?>
```

bottom.inc.php:

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: don't know if that makes a difference, but have you tried another syntax like `<?php if (1 == 1): ?>` `<?php endif; ?>` ?

Comment: Each file you include/require must be syntactically correct, so I do not think you can do what you ask in this way. What are you trying to obtain?

Comment: @MaxGherkins Yes, I have tried that! Makes no difference.

Comment: @MaxGherkins You can't do it either way

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I want to exclude the login condition in the top- and bottom-files that do already exist anyway. So i woudn't have to put this condition in every content file.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish; perhaps you could share more code with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Each .php file needs to have complete, valid syntax. `include`ing files is not exactly the same as copy-and-pasting their content.

Comment: +1. I think its a fault of php community who often tries make it super simple for newbies and ends up saying including is same as copy pasting.

Comment: @itachi - Guilty. I promise not do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. What you can do would be the following

in your `top.php`

```
<?php if($condition) { 
           include "bottom.inc.php";    
?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each file will need to have correct syntax. The easiest way would be to define a variable to hold a value that is say 1 if the statement is true.

Something like:

top.php

```
if (1 == 1) $value = 1;
```

index.php

```
if ($value == 1) // do something
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<?
file_put_contents("temp.php",file_get_contents("top.inc.php"));
$Middle_Code = <<<HEREDOC
/*
Other code to be put inside this heredoc,
but, of course, outside this comment block!
*/
HEREDOC;
file_put_contents("temp.php",$Middle_Code,FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents("temp.php",file_get_contents("bottom.inc.php"),FILE_APPEND);
require("temp.php");
```

Comment: I do hope this is only a tongue-in-cheek suggestion and not meant for actual consumption...

Comment: only if the asker really needs to do so :)

Comment: It doesn't even solve the problem in the question. Where is "some code to execute if statement in top.inc.php is true"?

Comment: Ok, but there should be some content between top.inc.php and bottom.inc.php that comes from the executed file itself (index.php).

Comment: this looks liek something that will only work if you have ONE person trying to access this at any given time ...

Comment: @PaulDinh Thanks. I should have made clearly that my overall goal is to get rid of some code in index.php. I better directly include the if statement instead of some workaround code. But thank you anyway.